# Convert current charset to windows-1252

Tags: vbscript, character-encoding

Hello I have a script in vbs that will send emails to desired destination

the problem is the output text is corrupted

**Current output :**  ils nâ€™ont

**Desired output :**  ils n'ont etc...

After research I found that I need to convert the text to windows 1252 in order to accept french characters

So I implemented the conversion functions :

```
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adTypeText = 2

//accept a string and convert it to Bytes array in the selected Charset
Function StringToBytes(Str,Charset)
  Dim Stream : Set Stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  Stream.Type = adTypeText
  Stream.Charset = Charset
  Stream.Open
  Stream.WriteText Str
  Stream.Flush
  Stream.Position = 0
  // rewind stream and read Bytes
  Stream.Type = adTypeBinary
  StringToBytes= Stream.Read
  Stream.Close
  Set Stream = Nothing
End Function

//accept Bytes array and convert it to a string using the selected charset
Function BytesToString(Bytes, Charset)
  Dim Stream : Set Stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  Stream.Charset = Charset
  Stream.Type = adTypeBinary
  Stream.Open
  Stream.Write Bytes
  Stream.Flush
  Stream.Position = 0
   // rewind stream and read text
  Stream.Type = adTypeText
  BytesToString= Stream.ReadText
  Stream.Close
  Set Stream = Nothing
End Function

' This will alter charset of a string from 1-byte charset(as windows-1252)
' to another 1-byte charset(as windows-1251)
Function AlterCharset(Str, FromCharset, ToCharset)
  Dim Bytes
  Bytes = StringToBytes(Str, FromCharset)
  AlterCharset = BytesToString(Bytes, ToCharset)
End Function
```

but how to detect the current encoding charest in order to convert them to windows-1252?

how should I call my function below properly?

```
  objEmail.Subject  = eSubject 
objEmail.Textbody = AlterCharset(eTextBody , "How to detect the current charset? ", "windows-1252") <--- how to write it properly here?
```

EDIT :

Doing this line of code did solve my char issues :

```
objEmail.Textbody = AlterCharset(eTextBody , "windows-1252 ", "UTF-8")
```

but the script will work on different PC , so I need to dynamically get the current charset in order to convert it to UTF-8